# Ajax returned data size

Tags: ajax, database, size

Been searching for some info on how much data an ajax call can receive/handle and haven't found anything.

The scenario is a common one: a call to the back-end to retrieve some rows from a database. The call can return any number of rows. The question is, how much data can I safely return to the front end?

Hope someone could shed some light on the subject.

Comment: anyone has any insight on how much data can be shipped through ajax calls? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The user can digest far fewer rows than you can safely return.  Either page the data for the user's benefit or provide searching/filtering options.

For a real answer, it's going to vary considerably for each browser, especially for mobile users, and depend a lot on each user's bandwidth and hardware.  This is one of those things where if you have to ask, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I do have searching and filtering. I was looking at different ways to handle this paging being one of them the other being infinite scrolling.  Paging resolves the technical and usability question. Infinite scrolling on the other hand does not address the technical aspect - how much content can the browser handle?  I was hoping for some technical limitations of the httprequest to use as a guideline.